# creating bottom sheet dialog with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create modal bottom sheet dialog to show a list of items which will be scrollable.

**dialog_bottom_example.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/white"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Items in LinearLayout is getting added dynamically based on list size as below:

**ExampleDialogBottom**:

```
class ExampleDialogBottom: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

private lateinit var binding: DialogExampleBinding
private var skusItems = mutableListOf<SkuItem>();

companion object {

    internal const val TAG = "ExampleDialogBottom"

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(nonEligibleErxItem: NonEligibleErxItem) = NonEligibleBottomDialog 
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DialogExampleBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    configureSkuItems()
}


private fun configureSkuItems() {
    if (!skuItems.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        for (sku in skuItems) {
            val skuItemView = SingleSkuItemViewBinding.inflate(inflater, null, false)
            skuItemView.skuImage.setImageWithVisibility(sku.imageUrl)
            skuItemView.skuTitle.setTextWithVisibility(sku.name)
            binding.container.addView(skuItemView.root)
        }
        binding.container.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        binding.container.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

**ExmpaleActivity:**

```
button.setOnClickListener {
     ExampleDialogBottom.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
      ExampleDialogBottom.TAG);
 }
```

However, when I click on button,  a transparent dialog shows up, **no content is showing**.

When I removed **match-contraint** and changed it **match-parent** or **wrap-content**, it's working as expected.

It would be great if someone could help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `drugContainer` the linearLayout?.. It's `container` in layout

Comment: yeah..it's the linear layout, edited.